# Trying to light a simple yoghurt cup, best way possible

Tags: modeling, lighting

[image]

I'm having a hard time trying to light this simple yoghurt cup the best way possible. I'm still learning blender, but I'm trying to make it look as professional as possible, lots of research have told me to do HDRI, or 3 point light system, but it does not seem right it still seems bland or off please does anyone have any suggestions.

I think its harder because I'm trying to light it with a transparent background, so I don't have the benefit of some light reflections. I see some material previews and the look so smooth and sharp even though its having one object in the middle.

Does anyone know the secret to achieving the look?

https://imgur.com/murnpPt

https://filebin.net/vkzmof85kptxv5oh/youghurt_cup.blend

Comment: Please add your image directly into your question rather than linking to it and share your file via https://blend-exchange.com/. That way both will still be available when people look at your question in future.

Comment: Even if it's transparent it will still have the HDRI image reflections and lights. Also you should use real lights, and don't forget to enable them for render in the Outliner

Comment: thank you! @JohnEason done!

Comment: that's the thing @moonboots, I've tried HDRI, but it still comes up flat. is it that im lighting it wrong, is there any good studio hdri i can use. i tried most in polyhaven but comes out unatural

Comment: Hello, Mark.. please give us a reference of 'the look' you're going for. otherwise we could all come up we the ways _we_ think are great for a yogurt-pot.. and which have nothing to do with what you want. At the moment this question is close to being closed  as 'opinion-based',  unless you give us a target.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the Tri-lighting plugin that comes with Blender.

To enable it, navigate to `Edit` > `Preferences` > Add-ons
Search for "Tri-lighting" and click the checkbox to enable it.
[image: screenshot of enabling tri-ligting plugin]

Now in your viewport, select the object you want to light and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and select `Light` > `3 Point Lights`

[image: screenshot of adding a 3 point light]

Now tweak the setting to your liking in the panel.

[image: screenshot of the 3 point lighting settings]

Profit.

Comment: alright, let me try that

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Add a plan on bottom and make a bevel like L-shape and place a 3-point light more light on top (may be it help to look perfect like in image)

Comment: i want to get this render lighting quality, but i don't want to add a plane, i want it to be transparent. you feel me?

Comment: Then make the plane transparent to the camera only, in object material properties.